# Get shares from a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, status

I have a `post_id`. I'm trying to retrieve the shares count of this post.

The post was published by an app, then in the `status_type` of this post I have `app_created_story`.

I'm using: `GET /post_id/shares` to have a response, but nothing, even if I know that this post  is been shared.

I notice that if I don't have an `app_created_story` the shares parameter work correctly.

Anyone knows this problem? Is this a bug?

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you sure that `app_created_story` posts are not giving shares, but normal ones are giving? I mean please try this by creating more posts and confirm this.

Comment: I have tried to share the first post (app_created_story) and then share the post shared. This second one has the shares parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve this via the

```
GET /{post_id}/sharedposts
```

edge. See documentation about this here

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/#edges
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/sharedposts

Comment: I have tried also in this way, but I have always the same result.

Comment: Have you gathered a Page Access Token with "read_stream" permission (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/)?

Comment: I think I have the read_stream permission because I see all the post parameters, but the only one that I cannot see is the shares one.

Comment: Try adding &summary=1 to your request: GET /{post_id}?summary=1